# can DOMXPath::query be limited to a certain depth?

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

Is there a way to limit the depth DOMXPath::query will look at?

Consider the following document:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

How could I limit the query

```
//div
```

So it only matches the first level and not the descendants?

Comment: Now it’s invalid HTML. A inline-level element like `span` can not contain block-level elements like `div`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will select the div elements that are not inside of any other div elements (similar to Gumbo's answer, but will check all levels, not just direct parent)

```
//div[not(ancestor::div)]
```

Comment: Excellent! You just saved me a recursive function. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try to describe the path from the root (single `/`):

```
/path/to/first/level/div
```

Or try this:

```
//div[not(parent::div)]
```

Comment: Apologies, it wasn't clear from my question that the parent element of the 2nd level or 3rd level is not necessarily a div, it could be any element.

Comment: @Aprikot: Then what is a first level `div`?